# Host Asp.Net Web Api Service on My Computer to access Remotely

Tags: asp.net-core, webapi

I created a default Asp.Net core 3.1 project with Web Api template, It contains weatherforecast controller with one method that is a Get() to retrieve random forecasts, I published this site to a folder on my computer and created a website in IIS manager that points to this directory using default application pool.

I entered my modem by typing 192.168.1.1 in the browser and Picked my ADSL IP address from it, Then I entered this IP address to bindings section in IIS and choose port 80 and http and a name for the site, Finally I enabled directory browsing in IIS and allowed world wide web service in the windows firewall, But when I enter: http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/SiteName/WeatherForecast (with xx... the IP I picked from modem)  using Get method in the PostMan or in the browser I get Error Message:

403 Forbidden

What is the source of this error and how to resolve this?

Comment: First thing to check is that whether the mapping is correct. Try hitting your page  http://your-external-IP  - If you are seeing the IIS page you need to look into the path. If you don't see the IIS page, you should look at the firewall to allow inbound connections on port 80.

Comment: when I enter external-IP the browser shows the "login to Modem" screen.

Comment: Do you have authorization implementation in controller?

Comment: no, I use the default asp.net template with no authorization.

Comment: Since you are seeing your modem page in the external ip, it means your routing is not proper. Please get help from the device's manual